# Cant get heroku server to work with firebase database? Heroku crashes?

Tags: html, node.js, firebase, heroku, web

Alright, Im really just missing a fundamental understanding here of what is going on. What I want to do is:

1. Use firebase for hosting and database - right now this works because I originally set the app up as a firebase app
2. Use Heroku for SERVER only - my reason is Google Cloud functions are limited and won't let me make external aPI calls on a free plan, etc

Im a little new to this setup but so far I have followed https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup and Heroku's setup instructions. My project - where public is my public html/files:

[image]

Ive run npm install and want to have heroku run server.js as my Server code. Running locally and officially, Ive been using

```
firebase serve 

firebase deploy
```

These both work without error, but no server code gets run. Trying `heroku open or heroku local`, it crashes with error:

> firebase experimental:functions:shell 2017-12-02T18:19:41.474319+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh 2017-12-02T18:19:41.471559+00:00
>   app[web.1]: sh: 1: firebase: not found

Here is server.js, just trying a simple test:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

// admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var serviceAccount = require("diverge-41a46-firebase-adminsdk-4yn47-29b6aaab49.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://diverge-41a46.firebaseio.com/"
});

'use strict';

console.log('HELLO WORLD');

const getIP = require('external-ip')();
var iplocation = require('iplocation');

// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

// exports.enterLocation = functions.database.ref('/Users/{name}') //brackets is client param
//     .onWrite(event => {
//       //console.log('SKYLAR HERE:', event.params.name);
//       returnLocation();
//       //-----------------------------------------
//
//       return event.data.adminRef.set({ location: 'test loc'});
//   });

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World');
})

app.listen(5000, function () { //process.env.PORT || 5000
console.log('Listening on port ', 5000);
})
```

and package.json (top part is left over from trying cloud functions):

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "external-ip": "^1.3.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.3",
    "iplocation": "^5.0.0",
    "request": "^2.83.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I downloaded my private key from Firebase when doing the `.initializeApp` bit as the tutorial states, so that should all be hooked up.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: any solutions on this?